# How to implement Linked List Recursion in KOtlin

Tags: kotlin, linked-list, recursive-datastructures

I am learning linked list and came across a problem where you are required to reverse a linked list using recursion. Here is the code I wrote:

```
fun reverseRecurseTraverse1(firstNode: Node<Int>?): Node<Int>? {
    if (firstNode?.next == null) {
        return firstNode
    } else {
        val finalNode = reverseRecurseTraverse1(firstNode.next)
        finalNode?.next = firstNode
        firstNode.next = null
        return finalNode
    }
}
```

```
Input:
01234

Output:
40
```

I get the desired output If I change the line from

```
finalNode?.next = firstNode
```

to

```
firstNode.next!!.next = firstNode
```

What am I doing wrong here?
When I try to whiteboard `finalNode?.next = firstNode` makes perfect sense to me and based on my understanding those two lines are essentially doing the same thing.
Kindly help me understand this.

Comment: A line which calls `next` once does the same as a line which calls it twice? Are you sure you understand what this `next` field is doing?

Comment: I think OP meant that according to their understanding of the algorithm, these to lines should point at the same object, so they should be functionally the same.

Answer (score 0):

It would be useful if you share your "whiteboard logic" and why do you assume `finalNode?.next = firstNode` is correct and functionally the same as `firstNode.next!!.next = firstNode`.

Let's get your example: `01234`. In the first step `firstNode` is `0` and after reversing of the remaining sublist, we get `4321`. `finalNode` points at the first element of this reversed sublist, so at `4`. Then you add `0` after `4` which is wrong. You should add `0` after `1`.

On the other hand, `firstNode.next` is still pointing at the item that was next to `0` in the original list. It points at `1`. By assigning to its `next` we add `0` where it should be - after `1`.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there, but one line is wrong.
What you are doing is:

If your item is null, return it. That seems okay.

If your item is already the last item, return it as first item. Also looks okay.

If your item is not the last item, reverse the rest of the list. Okay.

Take the old last and now first item, and append your old first now last item to it? That doesn't seem right. Don't you want to append your old first and now last item to the last item of the reversed rest?

It would probably help to write a function

```
fun Node.last(): Node? = if(next == null) this else next!!.last()
```

that provides the last item of a linked list.

You could use that to append your previously first item to the last item of the reversed rest.

Considering a call `reverseRecurseTraverse1(x)`, can we maybe always tell what `reverseRecurseTraverse1(x).last()` is without calculating it?